# How to find the smallest number in the array without sorting it?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, c++11

I am making a program which finds the smallest number in the array without sorting it.. The output is always 0. Please explain me why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {
    int num[5] = {5, 2, 1, 6, 9}, i, j;
    int min = num[0];

    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (min > num[i+1]) {
            min = num[i+1];
        }
    }
    printf("Smallest number is %d", min);

    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this expression: `num[i+1]` you're trying to access an element outside of the array - valid array indexes go from zero to the array's length minus one (which is `4` in this case, but `4+1` is out of the array).

And anyway you should not hard-code array lengths, write your loop like this instead:

```
for (i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
    if (num[i] < min) {
        min = num[i];
    }
}
```

That way it'll always work, it won't matter the actual length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

When `i` is `4` you are accessing `num[5]` which is outside the range of the array `num`. There are no guarantees what `num[5]` would be but most of the time there are couple trailing `0`'s after new memory allocation. It should be

```
for (i=1; i<5; i++) {
    if (min > num[i]) {
        min = num[i];
    }
}
```